# Histogram of image not showing expected distribution

Tags: arrays, matlab, histogram, threshold

I have a cell array called output. Output contains matrices of size 1024 x 1024, type = double, grayscale. I would like to plot each matrix and its corresponding histogram on a single plot. Here is what I have so far:

```
for i = 1:size(output,2)
    figure 
    subplot(2,1,1)
    imagesc(output{1,i});
    colormap('gray')
    colorbar;
    title(num2str(dinfo(i).name))

    subplot(2,1,2)
    [pixelCount, grayLevels] = imhist(output{1,i});
    bar(pixelCount);
    title('Histogram of original image');
    xlim([0 grayLevels(end)]); % Scale x axis manually.
    grid on;
end
```

The plot I get, however, seems to be faulty... I was expecting a distribution of bars.

[image]

I am somewhat lost at how to proceed, any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `hist` instead of `imhist`. I think `imhist` may require values in a range [0 255] or [0 1].

Comment: Didn't seem to help :(

Comment: Hmm, that's surprising. I've added a bit of detail for my comment in an answer below. If that still doesn't work for you, we'll need a sample of your data to help further. Try and construct a toy sample that has the same behavior but is small enough to include in a post ( 10x10 matrix for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the colorbar on your image plot the values of your image pixels range from [0, 5*10^6].

For many image processing functions, MATLAB assumes one of two color models, double values ranging from [0, 1] or integer values ranging from [0 255]. While the supported ranges are not explicitly mentioned in the `imhist` documentation, in the ["Tips" section of the `imhist` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html#buo3qvv-1), there is a table of scale factors for different numeric types that hints at these assumptions.

I think the discrepancy between your image range and these models is the root of the problem.

For example, I load a grayscale image and scale the pixels by 1000 to approximate your data.

```
% Toy data to approximate your image
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
output = {I, I .* 1000};

for i = 1:size(output,2)
    figure 
    subplot(2,1,1)
    imagesc(output{1,i});
    colormap('gray')
    colorbar;

    subplot(2,1,2)
    [pixelCount, grayLevels] = imhist(output{1,i});
    bar(pixelCount);
    title('Histogram of original image');
    grid on;
end
```

[image: Image with standard [0,1] double range]
[image: Image with non-standard[0, 1000] double range]

The first image is using a matrix with the standard [0,1] double value range. The `imhist` calculates a histogram as expected. The second image is using a matrix with the scaled [0, 1000] double value range. `imhist` assigns all the pixels to the 255 bin since that is the maximum bin. Therefore, we need a method that allows us to scale the bins.

### Solution : Use `histogram`

[`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) is designed for any numeric type and range. You may need to fiddle with the bin edges to show the structures that you are interested in as it doesn't initialize bins the same way `imhist` does.

```
figure 
subplot(2,1,1)
imagesc(output{1,2});
colormap('gray')
colorbar;

subplot(2,1,2)
histogram(output{1,2});
title('Histogram of original image');
grid on;
```

[image]

Comment: That you so much for the thorough response!!! It solved the issue :)

http://imgur.com/a/VXq4J